# Can anyone tell me how to run my existing project on emulator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-emulator

I have switched my emulator [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqN1w.png)

But it's still not connected [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFGKk.png)

How can I connect my emulator???[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jszA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can install JDK again from [here](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) and set the environment variables for Java then try to run your application again on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the emulator is connected, via command `adb devices`.
Also check, your error is `couldn't found tools.jar`. Please check if you have valid JDK installation.

Answer (score 0):

1.Please check if you have valid JDK installed or not
2.Please check you have android environment setup or not via this link, [environment setup link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)
3.check device connected or not from terminal - adb-devices